# MySQL reading the wrong column?

Tags: php, mysql

This is absolutely puzzling me. I've done queries like this tons of times before but this one seems to have an issue. I've even completely dropped the table and re-added it so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Basically I have a table called friends where one user (sender_id) can send a friend request to another user (receiver_id), the status is originally set to zero and then when the receiver accepts the friend request the status is updated to 1.

On the Friends page, it lists all of the logged in user's friends with the friend's avatar, username, etc. However, the value "friend_id" is pulling the ROW NUMBER (column id) instead of the "other user id" (either sender_id or receiver_id depending on who sent the request...whatever is NOT the logged in user).

Friends table set-up: id (INT 15, unique, primary), sender_id (INT 15), receiver_id (INT 15), created (datetime), status = (INT 1)

```
$getfriends = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE sender_id = '$user_id' OR receiver_id = '$user_id' ORDER BY status ASC, id DESC LIMIT $offset, $user_friends_limit", $conn);
```

then some code to set up the table

```
while ($rowfriends = mysql_fetch_assoc($getfriends)) {

$relationship_id = $rowfriends['id']; // this doesn't actually need to be called since I don't need to use this number
$sender_id = $rowfriends['sender_id'];
$receiver_id = $rowfriends['receiver_id'];
$friend_status = $rowfriends['status'];
$friend_date = $rowfriends['created'];


// THE IMPORTANT PART THAT ASSIGNS THE FRIEND ID
if($sender_id == "$user_id"){
    $friend_id = "$receiver_id";
}
else {
    $friend_id = "$sender_id";
}

if($friend_status == 0){
     $since = "Request Sent";
}
elseif($friend_status == 1){
     $since = "Friend Since";
}

// FUNCTIONS --- ALL OF THE FUNCTIONS ARE RETURNING WITH THE WRONG INFO
User($friend_id);
Avatar($friend_id);
ProfileURL($friend_id);
UserFavorites($friend_id);
UserPoints($friend_id);
UserPosts($friend_id);
DateConvert($friend_date);
```

Then some code to display the results

It seems like when the friend_id = 1 AS in when the user with the id 1 either sends or receives a friend request, then friend_id is pulling the ROW number or relationship_id instead, otherwise it looks like its working. I'm just not sure why this is happening.

For example, if I replace $sender_id = $rowfriends['sender_id']; to $sender_id = RAND(2, 2000); it displays the correct avatar, user name, etc for the user with whatever random id that is generated. It doesn't work when the user is 1.

**ANSWER**

I posted the answer below but I cannot accept it yet.

Comment: why this question is tagged with mysql error?

Comment: because it was not computing correctly for some odd reason. I still don't know why it was doing what it was doing but I decided to just rename my variable and it worked

Comment: so, you just added a random error number of which you have no idea what is it for? that's the root of all your problem.

Comment: What? I don't know what you mean. There was an ERROR in the way that my query was calling my data. it was calling the INCORRECT information though my code was written correctly. Something was wrong with the variable, I changed the variable name and everything worked. Did you even READ my question? I put the tag as mysql error because I am using mysql and there was an ERROR

Comment: yes, I did. even the "answer" you added. and it is clear that mysql has nothing to do with this "error". if it was indeed "incorrect data", you were unable to do `$friend = "$sender_id";`. Go figure.

Comment: no $friend = "$sender_id" DID work, $friend_id (noted the _id at the end) WOULD not work for some reason. Everything about my code was correct. Only when sender or receiver equalled 1 it would pull the row number (column id) INSTEAD of the user's id number.

Comment: What did you edit? There was absolutely nothing that needed to be edited?

Comment: Ok I see what you were saying about the error tag, I did not mean to chose that I guess I wasn't paying full enough attention, but still nothing else needed to be edited.

Comment: `I wasn't paying full enough attention` is the only your problem. that's what I am talking about.

Comment: ok first off all the only INCORRECT thing about my entire post was the wrong tag which you removed, fine. I don't know what your problem is. This is a valid question if you don't have an answer for why $friend was working and not $friend_id then you don't need to be posting. That was the entire issue with my code and I don't know why. I have a work around by using $friend but I am still curious to know why $friend_id would not work.

Comment: oh no, you are wrong :) this is not "the only INCORRECT thing". you don't pay "full enough attention" again. As I explained above, the title is absolutely incorrect, for example, too. As it turned to be that you have problems with your code assigning values, not the value itself. This is called "logic" and it lacks in both your code and your question.

Comment: ok instead of just saying this and that is incorrect could you please explain why. What part of the above code is wrong? I don't understand why when a variable equals a certain value, that it causes it to not work but then when I rename the variable, everything works. How about you actually be HELPFUL and point out exactly what is wrong, otherwise, why are you here? Not just for me but the other person that tried to answer, their solution was also incorrect so perhaps they do not know what the issue was.

Comment: I did explain why. It seems you just don't read my explanations. Or you don't understand them. It is based on the logic thing and it seems you aren't quite familiar with it. May be you need to take some classes on the subject.

Comment: How is the logic incorrect when I retrieve all the values from the desired columns (id, sender, receiver, and the user is already set). I display those values immediately and they display correctly but when I say "if this then that", that is where the issue is? How is that a problem with "assigning values to the variable" when all of the variable values are correct?

Comment: `I display those values immediately and they display correctly` means there is no mysql error - right?

Comment: finally figured out what the issue was, and no Col it wasn't anything you said

Comment: make sure you was paying full enough attention making this statement ;)

Comment: lol no it's legit but I don't wanna post it cuz I feel silly all that is important is my makeshift answer works. Thanks but it wouldn't hurt to be less rude.

Comment: fixed the underlying issue, everything is working even changed $friend back to $friend_id and it's computing correctly.

ok so maybe it was a logic issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed and re-added each line of the code, turns out the User AND Avatar function, which were both recently modified, included a function that included a function (very deeply hidden) that had the $friend_id variable already set globally. I renamed that variable $relationship_id as it was the column "id" in the "friends" table. This allowed my original code to work.

```
if($user_id == $receiver_id){
    $friend_id = "$sender_id";
}
else {
    $friend_id = "$receiver_id";
}
```

Obviously using the variable $friend with no _id at the end worked before I figured out the exact problem because there weren't two conflicting values for that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You coded:

```
    // THE IMPORTANT PART THAT ASSIGNS THE FRIEND ID
    if($sender_id == "$user_id"){
...
```

but I don't see that $user_id is being set.

Comment: user id is a global variable, it's on every page

Answer (score 0):

sessions combined with register globals may rewrite variables.
it is impossible to say anything more with not a sign of debugging. Say, to answer the question "MySQL reading the wrong column?" one don't have to put a whole page of code between value retrieval and it's verification. Why can't you display this column value right after getting it from the database?

also note that auto increment unique identifier field IS NOT a row number by any means. such a false assumption WILL cause another "mysterious" error like this one.
also note that unlike strings, variables in PHP should be addressed without quotes. such a false usage WILL cause another "mysterious" error like this one.

Comment: no used quotes and also did not use quotes and I guess i didn't mean row number but instead it was calling the id column, which ever value that was, when sender or receiver was equal to 1 it would call the id column instead. changing friend_id to friend made it work, I do not know why. I echoed the user id, sender id, receiver id and the column "id" and they all displayed correctly, it was just the error with friend_id = etc